# how to change the space value with% 20 in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a problem, I'm doing a test with jmeter and I need to know how to change the value of a variable that has a space, example "pro va" with "pro% 20va" this because then this variable will be used to do a query on an endpoint example "www.google.com/search?q=pro%20va"

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [__javaScript() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) to call [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function:

   ```
   ${__javaScript(encodeURIComponent("${myVar}"),)}
   ```
2. Put your variable in "Path" field of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler - it will be encoded automatically

   [image]

Demo:

[image]

If you have the choice - go for 2nd option as using JavaScript is some form of [performance anti-pattern](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), if you target to use the approach for high loads - it's better to implement the encodeURIComponent() function in [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: in case I am taking the value from a random csv I have to use a JSR223 PostProcessor and insert the expression inside?